# Content Security Policy not applying to html

Tags: html, node.js, content-security-policy

I have set content security policy(CSP) in nodejs and it is getting applied to node. However, for the root html page CSP is not being applied. How can it be applied on html with the help of nodejs.

```
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' ");
    return next();
});
```

Comment: Is the root HTML page served by this node server?

Comment: Yes, index.html page

Comment: If I check the the home page in security headers https://securityheaders.com/ - it says missing CSP headers

Comment: And that use is before the static middleware in your sequence? Would you have a minimum reproduction ?

Comment: Yes, before the static middleware I have set the CSP headers

Comment: Same! Api endpoints have their CSP applied but not html files

Answer (score 0):

**Scroll down for express server implementation**

I tried using **restify** instead of express server and using almost the same code as express, you can set the CSP and X-Frame-Options header for static files.

```
const restify = require("restify");
const { join } = require("path");

const server = restify.createServer();

// Middleware to set X-Frame-Options and Content Security Policy (CSP) headers
server.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
  const allowedDomain = "https://my-website.com";
  res.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", `frame-ancestors ${allowedDomain}`);
  return next();
});

// Serve static files from the 'public' directory
server.get(
  "/*",
  restify.plugins.serveStatic({
    directory: join(__dirname, "public"),
    default: "index.html",
  })
);

server.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 8080");
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
const { join } = require("path");

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// Middleware to set X-Frame-Options and Content Security Policy (CSP) headers
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
  const allowedDomain = "https://my-website.com/";
  res.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", `frame-ancestors ${allowedDomain}`);
  return next();
});

// Serve static files from the 'public' directory
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, "public")));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 8080");
});
```